# How to remove featured image form WordPress post?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress based blog where I want to remove the featured image.

```
.single-post .attachment-post-thumbnail {
    display: none;
}
```

I cannot find above code in `single.php` or in any CSS file. Now I don't know how to remove the featured image.

http://www.blogginggadgets.com/xiaomi-redmi-note-prime-price-specifications-features-review/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
.article-featured-image {
    display: none !important;
}
```

It will look like this:

[image: Preview:]

Comment: You are welcome! :D Hope you can set this up as the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `functions.php` it will remove that feature image.

```
add_filter( 'wp_head', 'filter_function_name' );
function filter_function_name(){
echo '<style>.article-featured-image{display: none!important;}</style>';        
}
```

Comment: tell me any particular place where i have to add this .

Comment: Goto Appearance → [Editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen) and find functions.php  and paste above code just bellow on `<?php`

Comment: or simply add `<style>.article-featured-image{display: none!important;}</style>` to your `header.php` bellow of `<head>`

Comment: Download this plugin and install [plugin](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xx98rephmhis2ks/hide-feature-image.zip?dl=1)

Comment: if the answer helpful try to upvote and accept answer